# Python - how to print entire output from command?

Tags: python

I have a python script that execute a few commands and I have added a print(stdout) to print the output but it's not working:

```
class CalledProcessError(RuntimeError):
    pass

def cmd_output(*cmd: str, retcode: Optional[int] = 0, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    kwargs.setdefault('stdout', subprocess.PIPE)
    kwargs.setdefault('stderr', subprocess.PIPE)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    stdout = stdout.decode()
    print(stdout)
    if retcode is not None and proc.returncode != retcode:
        raise CalledProcessError(cmd, retcode, proc.returncode, stdout, stderr)
    return stdout
```

It is only printing last line of command. As example:

```
cmd_output(
        'git', 
        'push', 
        '--set-upstream', 'origin', 'xpto123', 
        '-o', 'merge_request.create', 
        '-o', 'merge_request.target=banana', 
        '-o', 'merge_request.label=dependencies')
```

It prints:

```
Branch 'xpto123' set up to track remote branch 'xpto123' from 'origin'.
```

If I run the git command inside my terminal, it shows a lot of information like:

```
~/repos/gov (xpto123 ✔) ᐅ git push --set-upstream origin xpto123 -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=banana -o merge_request.label=dependencies
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 396 bytes | 396.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote:
remote: View merge request for xpto123:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/ausgov/whatever/merge_requests/45
Branch 'xpto123' set up to track remote branch 'xpto123' from 'origin'.
```

Any idea why my `stdout` shows only the last line?

Comment: What python version are you using? There are simpler ways of doing this...

Comment: Have you tried printing `stderr`?